# Nordic DFU process in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, dfu, nordic-semi

I have a [Xamarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xamarin) Forms (XF) application that implements the following NuGet package to utilize Nordic's [OTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-air_update) [DFU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Device_Firmware_Upgrade) process. *[Laerdal.Dfu](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Laerdal.Dfu/)*

This package worked in XF, but now that I am transition to .NET MAUI, there are some issues. I was wondering if anyone has any experience in using this package in .NET MAUI?

There is currently an open issue regarding this, but there does not seem to be any urgency to fix it at the moment. *[DfuInstallation.Start() Exception thrown on .Net MAUI #27](https://github.com/Laerdal/Laerdal.Dfu/issues/27)*

Transition from an XF application to a .NET MAUI application to use Nordic DFU NuGet from Laerdal.

Comment: what are "some issues"?

Comment: I attached the issues through Github in the last link. It is throwing this exception after selecting a firmware file and BT chip address. Exception of type 'Foundation.You_Should_Not_Call_base_In_This_Method' was thrown.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  The relevant details of your question need to be included in the body of the post, not just in a link to an offsite resource.